# Display first few rows using QtSql.QSqlTableModel with QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I'm trying to display only 5 rows of my table from a SQLite database file which I used QSqlTableModel to gain access and QTableView to display on the UI.

I have looked it up but yet to find a function in either QSqlTableModel or QTableView to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you choose those five elements?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I sort them by the date column and pick the first 5 most recent ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use `setFilter("id limit 5")` but this method places `"Where"` before the string and this causes that when I want to use `setSort()` it generates a syntax error problem in the order, so I discard it.

For this reason I propose the following solution, which is to create a class that inherits from `QSqlTableModel` and to override the `selectStatement()` method.

**sqltablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef SQLTABLEMODEL_H
#define SQLTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>

class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    int mLimit;
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SqlTableModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase()): QSqlTableModel(parent, db)
    {
        mLimit = -1;
    }

    int limit() const{
        return mLimit;
    }
    void setLimit(int limit){
        if(limit > 0)
            mLimit = limit;
    }

protected:
    QString selectStatement() const
    {
        QString query = QSqlTableModel::selectStatement();
        if(mLimit > 0)
            query += QString(" LIMIT %1").arg(mLimit);
        return query;
    }
};

#endif // SQLTABLEMODEL_H
```

Then you change the QSqlTableModel to the SqlTableModel class and you use the `setLimit()`

Example:

```
SqlTableModel *model = new SqlTableModel();
model->setTable("person");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setSort(0, Qt::DescendingOrder);
model->setLimit(5);
model->select();
//print query
qDebug()<<model->query().lastQuery();
```

Output:

```
"SELECT \"id\", \"firstname\", \"lastname\" FROM person ORDER BY person.\"id\" DESC LIMIT 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the setFilter("LIMIT 5") that generate something similar to this:

```
WHERE (LIMIT 5)
```

Which is totally wrong. Just check it with the selectStatement() and you will see.

Maybe this trick is not nice but shorter, just correct that Sql query with a little SQL-injection:

```
setFilter("1) LIMIT 5;#")
```

It will generete this:

```
WHERE (1) LIMIT 5;#)
```